# xmpp openfire push notification and logging

Tags: java, push-notification, xmpp, openfire, messenger

I am building the java backend for an app (android & ios) which has a messenger function integrated.

I was playing around with openfire and ejabberd the last days and was wondering how i can solve my problem - I want to catch all messages from and to Server for

1. log messages to custom history file
2. send push notifications to android & ios client when offline.

Has anyone implemented something like this yet? I have read something about a xmpp proxy doing that work but i really dont know how to start.

thanks in advance.
- bob

Comment: Check google cloud messenger GCM for notification and this plugin for openfire https://github.com/meisterfuu/Openfire-GCM

Comment: Improved formatting and readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: log messages to custom history file: For Openfire, you can write your custom plugin with packet interceptor and you can log information as per your business needs. You can definitely find opensource plugins for this, but as per my experience, I have done custom work to log specific information.

2: send push notifications to android & ios client when offline: Again my experience is with custom solution as per Business needs. Custom code can be injected in your Openfire code and you can send http request to your push server (or You can send push directly to GCM or Apple by determining the platform of recipient). Custom code also provides you the ability to send as much information as you require. Like, You can send actual chat message in push, or if you want to send some customized message in push.

but i really dont know how to start: If you are willing to perform custom changes for your business needs, then hurry to checkout Openfire code from Github and set up development environment.
For Openfire Plugin Development, You can start with the plugin development guide: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html